# How does realm queries work?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to understand Realm.

https://academy.realm.io/posts/jp-simard-realm-core-database-engine/

[image]

I am trying to understand what does the speaker mean 
**We are essentially building a tree what this results should look like**

I think he meant that the Realm will read all objects with name and fulltime properties but not any other properties and then checks if the name is Jack and fulltime is true. Is realm iterating through all objects?

Comment: Please include code formatted as code and not as a screenshot when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think he meant that the Realm will read all objects with name and fulltime properties but not any other properties and then checks if the name is Jack and fulltime is true.

Not exactly. Realm get only objects that conform to filter queries.

> Is realm iterating through all objects?

You can read in [`Realm` docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) about queries that:

> All queries (including queries and property access) are `lazy` in Realm. Data is `only read` when the properties are accessed.

So, `Realm` return only (i believe) `Results<Employee>` that contains filtered objects, but technically read them from `realm-db` only in moment when you try to access them.

Comment: Katsumi from Realm here. pacification's answer is correct. `objects()` or `filter()` returns `Results<T>`, `Results<T>` is a proxy object. It just contains query meta data. Realm defers copying data until you access a property of elements.